# LambdaMetaFactory with Generic Static Methods?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, methodhandle, lambda-metafactory

So I'm creating a library that allows users to pass a `Class<?>` and collect all static methods with a specific annotation (and other criteria, such as a certain parameter count and types) and convert them into lambda `FunctionalInterfaces` that my library will use internally for processing.

For example:

Say I have the following class tree:

```
public abstract class AbstractParent {
  
  public String sayHi() {
    return getClass().getName() + " instance says hi!";
  }

}
```

with subclasses:

```
public class ChildOne extends AbstractParent {

  public int childOneSpecialMethod() {
    return 2558445;
  }
}
```

```
public class ChildTwo extends AbstractParent {

  public int childTwoSpecialMethod() {
    return 484848;
  }
  
}
```

My library allows for users to annotate a class's static methods with the following annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ProcessAnnotation {}
```

with the following rules: the static method first parameter be an instance of `AbstractParent`, and its second parameter must be a `String`, and must return a `String`. So, something like this:

```
public class GeneralProcessor {
  
  @ProcessAnnotation
  public static String easyProcessing(ChildOne one, String otherArg) {
    //Some code
    System.out.println(" === In processing for ChildOne types");
    return otherArg + one.toString();
  }

  @ProcessAnnotation
  public static String easyProcessing(ChildTwo two, String otherArg) {
    //Some code
    System.out.println(" === In processing for ChildTwo types");
    return otherArg + two.toString();
  }
}
```

On the library-side of things, I want to collect all these methods so that I can use them for some processing while doing it in a relatively fast manner and I found that `MethodHandles` and `LambdaMetaFactory` is the best way to do this.

Specifically, I want to invoke these collected methods using my own `FunctionalInterface` :

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ProcessInterface<T extends AbstractParent> {
  
  public String process(T obj, String extraArg);
}
```

So far, what I've tried is something like this:

```
public static List<ProcessInterface<? extends AbstractParent>> generate(Class<?> targetClass) throws Throwable {
    ArrayList<ProcessInterface<? extends AbstractParent>> processors = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Method method : targetClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
      if (method.isAnnotationPresent(ProcessAnnotation.class) &&
          method.getParameterCount() == 2 && 
          AbstractParent.class.isAssignableFrom(method.getParameterTypes()[0]) &&
          method.getParameterTypes()[1] == String.class) {
        
        MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
        MethodHandle handle = lookup.unreflect(method);
        CallSite callSite = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, 
                                                          "process", 
                                                          MethodType.methodType(ProcessInterface.class), 
                                                          MethodType.methodType(String.class, 
                                                                                method.getParameterTypes()[0],
                                                                                String.class), 
                                                          handle, 
                                                          handle.type());

        ProcessInterface<? extends AbstractParent> func = (ProcessInterface<? extends AbstractParent>) callSite.getTarget().invoke();
        processors.add(func);
      }
    }

    return processors;
  }
```

However, I get the following error when I actually invoke the lambda. For example:

```
List<ProcessInterface<? extends AbstractParent>> interfaces = generate(GeneralProcessor.class);

ChildOne childOne = new ChildOne();
interfaces.get(0).process(childOne, "");
```

Is there a fix to do this? Or maybe even a better way to achieve this?

Comment: What is "the following error"? You seem to have forgot to include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is inherently not type safe. How do you ensure that `interfaces.get(0)` can process a `ChildOne`? What if it takes a `ChildTwo` instead?

This is why you are not allowed to pass `childOne` to `interfaces.get(0).process`. `interfaces.get(0)` is a `ProcessInterface<Something>`, but you don't know what `Something` is. It could be `ChildOne`, or `ChildTwo`. This is what the type `ProcessInterface<? extends AbstractParent>` *means*. See also [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

If `Something` were actually `ChildTwo`, then passing a `ChildOne` will not work at all. The implementing method does not know how to deal with that. In fact, you can only safely pass `null` to `process`.

So let's suppose the user's of your library are responsible for ensuring that type safety, and that you are sure that this is always safe.

In that case, cast `generate`'s return value to `List<ProcessorInterface<AbstractParent>>`:

```
List<ProcessInterface<AbstractParent>> interfaces = 
    (List<ProcessInterface<AbstractParent>>)(Object)generate(GeneralProcessor.class);
```

(You can change the return type of `generate` to this type, if you really want.)

`ProcessInterface<AbstractParent>` is a type that you can pass all kinds of `AbstractParent`s to its `process` method. In fact, since type safety is gone at this point, it doesn't matter which exact type you cast to, as long as it can take any `AbstractParent`.

Now if you happen to pass the wrong type of instance to `process`, a `ClassCastException` will be thrown.

As for your `LambdaMetafactory`, you should pass the method type of the *interface method* for the fourth argument of `metafactory`, not the implementing method's method type.

```
CallSite callSite = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup,
        "process",
        MethodType.methodType(ProcessInterface.class),
        // this should be the interface method's type
        MethodType.methodType(String.class, AbstractParent.class, String.class),
        handle,
        handle.type());
```

Comment: The last argument is not the implementing method's type but the interface method’s type after applying type arguments (which happens to be the same here). The implementing method’s type is implied by the method handle and doesn’t need to be specified.

Comment: @Holger Oh that’s a very subtle difference! I didn’t think much about it.

Comment: It’s important for conversions, first interface method arguments get cast (for reference types) according to the type specified as last arg, then (un)boxing conversions may occur to adapt to the target method handle types. For the return value, it’s the opposite order. First (un)boxing (or dropping), then reference type conversion. For example, when binding `StringBuilder.append(int)` to `BiConsumer<StringBuilder, Integer>` you have `(Object,Object)-> void` as 3rd argument, `(StringBuilder, Integer)-> void` as last argument and `(StringBuilder,int)-> StringBuilder` implied by the method handle